# Laravel access denied for storing model into database

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to send my model into database via ajax in Laravel.

**Here is my ajax call**

```
    $('.btn-like').click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'like',
        type: 'POST'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }); 

    });
```

**And here is my route**

```
Route::post('like', [
    'uses' => 'DefaultController@like'
]);
```

**and Here Like function in the DefaultController controller**

```
public function like()
{
    $like = new Like();
    $like->save();
}
```

**And here hte Like model**

```
class Like extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'likes';

}
```

**And this is error what I get**

```
Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
```

btw. here is how I set my env

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('Itachi'),

));
```

does anyone know where can be problem?

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: do you have an `app/config/local/database.php`? I suspect no.  If not, do you have a mysql database set up with a user named `homestead` that matches the credentials found in `app/config/database.php`?

Comment: could you please send post this comment as an aswer your suggestion was right :)

Comment: I would, but @ihkawiss is pretty much answering the same, so go ahead and give the tick to him instead :) glad to help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your defined database credentials within `app/config/database.php` are wrong.

Please make sure your database settings are correct. Also check if provided user `homestead` has permissions for selected database.

More information here: http://laravel.com/docs/database